# How to encode Apple ProRes on Windows or Linux?

Tags: encoding, codec, windows, linux, prores

Is it also possible to encode video with Apple ProRes on Windows and Linux?

Comment: Aside the better (because multiplatform) answers given by the other users in past there was also this plugin for premiere: http://www.miraizon.com/products/codecsoverview.html but if you try to buy it it says that sales are ended, i wonder why. I suggest you ffmpeg too ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of December 2018, Adobe Creative Cloud aps, such as Premier, [<strike>After Effects and</strike>](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/kb/export-h264.html#main-pars_header_0) Adobe Media Encoder give you the ability to [encode in ProRes](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/whats-new.html) without any *post-hoc* conversion.

If you don't use Adobe CC aps or want a free, open source tool, `ffmpeg` can encode video using ProRes, and runs cross-platform. `ffmpeg` is a command line tool, which means that it can be automated.

There are a plethora of [free GUIs for ffmpeg](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=foss+gui+for+ffmpeg) for those unfamiliar with the command line.

This `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le output.mov
```

will do the trick.

The `-profile` switch takes an integer from -1 to 5 to match the ProRes profiles:

- -1: `auto` (default)
- 0: `proxy` ≈ 45Mbps YUV 4:2:2
- 1: `lt` ≈ 102Mbps YUV 4:2:2
- 2: `standard` ≈ 147Mbps YUV 4:2:2
- 3: `hq` ≈ 220Mbps YUV 4:2:2
- 4: `4444`≈ 330Mbps YUVA 4:4:4:4
- 5: `4444xq` ≈ 500Mbps YUVA 4:4:4:4

The approximate bit-rates are for 1920×1080p footage. All of the profiles are progressive, 10-bit, and little-endian (byte order).

The profiles are explained on the [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202410). There doesn't as yet seem to be support for RGBA encoding in 4444 and 444xq which the official Apple codec supports.

<strike>You may also use `prores` instead of `prores_ks`, which may be a little faster, but does not offer the 4444 profiles. For more background, please read [this FFmpeg Wiki article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VFX#Prores)</strike>. The prores_ks encoder is now default, and you only need to specify `prores` in the command, even when encoding prores 4444.

Comment: Could you expand to say what the different profiles are and what they mean?

Comment: @hellocatfood I added a link to the Apple website which explains the profiles.

Comment: *little-endian — whatever that means* --> The decoded 10-bit samples are actually stored as padded 16 bits. The lower 8 bits are presented first, followed by the upper 8 bits. Big endian is upper 8 followed by lower 8.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried a bunch of front ends for ffmpeg and finally settled on **[Tencoder](http://tencoder.sourceforge.net/)**. Widows only. It has a preset for ProRes and is very easy to customize so you can crete setting for often used formats or settings.
It is multithreaded and allows you to do batch processing.

[image]

Comment: The link you posted doesn't take you to a TEncoder download, instead try this one: https://www.fosshub.com/TEncoder-Video-Converter.html

Comment: @cegaton Strange, your screenshot looks a little like that of [WinFF](https://github.com/WinFF/winff)

Comment: @cegaton Your [Tencoder](https://tencoder.sourceforge.net) link is redirecting to [Internet Friendly Media Encoder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ifme). And btw : http://ifme.sf.net/ is redirecting to https://x265.github.io/

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I recommend [FootageStudio 4K](http://vegasaur.com/FootageStudio4k). It is a commercial converter (not cheap) that supports many professional formats, including ProRes.

Comment: If you look at their download page, in the licensing info at the bottom they state that they use libavcodec and ffmpeg software in their product. So you're paying for the fancy GUI by the looks of it.

Comment: "Libav codecs from FFMPEG project" - I think that this is not the same as another interface for ffmpeg.exe

Comment: It does seem to look pretty good if you don't / can't use the command line I guess. Still, this grumpy old fart would rather use ffmpeg and spend the money on whisky.

Answer (score 3):

This is the command line I have used to encode ProRes 4444. If you do not include `-bits_per_mb` you will get low res results in Windows 10. Many posts do not mention this little aspect.

`ffmpeg -y -f mov -i input-file.mov -vcodec prores_ks -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -profile:v 4444 -bits_per_mb 8000 -s 1920x1080 output-file.mov`

Comment: This is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ffmbc](https://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/) - a customized version of FFmpeg. Unfortunately there are no builds for linux or windows at the moment so you have compile it yourself.

Related: [What is the difference between ffmpeg and ffmbc now?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14727/what-is-the-difference-between-ffmpeg-and-ffmbc-now)

Comment: What advantage does ffmbc have over the regular ffmpeg in the current scenario?

Comment: @BartArondson In this case it is irrelevant, but if you are working for Broadcast you can integrate all the other features of ffmbc to your pipeline. See this: https://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/

Comment: I used to use ffmbc before ffmpeg had proRes support, but I can't see any difference between ffmpeg and ffmbc now.